# AS3 Bring button to front on mouse over

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6, tween

I'm using this code to animate the buttons on the contact page of a website I'm designing.

```
//Contact Buttons
//Email
ContactPage.Email.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,bounceEmailover);

function bounceEmailover(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var scaleTween:Tween=new Tween(event.target,"scaleX",Elastic.easeOut,1,1.5,1,true);
    var scale2Tween:Tween=new Tween(event.target,"scaleY",Elastic.easeOut,1,1.5,1,true);
}

ContactPage.Email.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,bounceEmailout);

function bounceEmailout(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var scaleTween:Tween=new Tween(event.target,"scaleX",Elastic.easeOut,1.5,1,1,true);
    var scale2Tween:Tween=new Tween(event.target,"scaleY",Elastic.easeOut,1.5,1,1,true);
}
```

There are 4 buttons with the same code lined up across the page that I want to bounce out and overlap when I mouse over. Is there a way to bring the button I've moused over to the front instead of staying behind the button next to it?

[Here's an image of the buttons](http://content.screencast.com/users/Futret/folders/Jing/media/8bd1baea-0ff9-4a17-87cd-3abd1bff431b/2016-11-06_1254.png). The Wordpress button has been moused over but it stays behind the Facebook button.

Answer (score 1):

simply get an instance of that button, then remove it from its container list, then add back it to top of the list

```
function bounceEmailover(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var scaleTween:Tween=new Tween(event.target,"scaleX",Elastic.easeOut,1,1.5,1,true);
    var scale2Tween:Tween=new Tween(event.target,"scaleY",Elastic.easeOut,1,1.5,1,true);

    var parent:MovieClip = event.target.parent as MovieClip;
    var btn:MovieClip = event.target as MovieClip;
    parent.addChild(btn);
}
```

**Edit:** thanks to @NealDavis, removed `parent.addChild(btn);`from above as:

> removeChild is unneeded here. Callig addChild for an
>   object that is already in existence will not create a second instance,
>   but only move the already crated instance to the top of the z-order

make sure `getChildByName` and `removeChild` and `addChild` called from right place

Comment: Where would I actually put this? Sorry, I'm new.

Comment: No need to call removeChild.

Comment: I get this error when I add your code :'(
"Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 457 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method addChild through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject."

Comment: @user7083681 movieClip is an implemented DisplayObject, so you can easily convert it to MovieClip, try the edited code again,

Answer (score 1):

Since all of the buttons are embedded within the Contact Page movie clip, I was able to add this code to just the Contact page which brings any button within that movie clip to the front when I mouse over. Works fine.

```
for (var fl_ChildIndex:int = 0;
        fl_ChildIndex < this.numChildren;
        fl_ChildIndex++)
{
    this.getChildAt(fl_ChildIndex).addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, fContactMObringtofront);
}
function fContactMObringtofront(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    this.addChild(event.currentTarget as DisplayObject);
}
```